# failed to load viewstate with Report Viewer

Tags: reportviewer2008, failed-to-load-viewstate

I am using Report Viewer 9.0 in .NET Framework 4.0, and changing the ServerURL and ReportPath whenever I click a link button with a different command argument. But the reportviewer failed to load viewstate, giving erros such as:
The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.

Anyone has met a similar issue and solved it before? Please help me...